# How can I see the calendar from Android work and private profiles together?

Tags: calendar, restricted-profiles, android-enterprise, android-for-work

The organization I work at has added the option of using Android For Work (AFW) aka Android Enterprise (AE).  Under this setup I have two profiles: private and work.  These are completely separate spaces, so apps installed in one profile aren't available in the other, and files are kept separate.  Even Android's *share* functionality is separate, so I can't share a file I received at work to my private profile.

The only thing that I've seen that is somewhat shared is the phone app.  When I search for a contact, I get results from both work and private profiles.

The question is, is there any way to view my work and private calendars together?  While the profiles are separate, there is only one me, so I would like to be able to see all my schedule constraints in one place.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: no, this doesn't help.  In my case I want the opposite - view calendars from two profiles on a single widget (or app)

Comment: See if [calendar widgets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_widgets) from Izzy's list can help

Comment: It doesn't look like it would help, because all of those widgets are apps that are installed either in the work profile or in the private profile.  Apps that are in one profile can't access data from the other.

Comment: Yes. This issue has been raised last year in Google forums and apparently there is no way unless you can export to Gmail or have a common account provider for calendars https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpEUzTYjxDEQjs/?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You can share your work calendar with your private id or share your private calendar with work id. This way you can see both calendar together.

This applies if it is google calendar for both work and private use.

Please let us know if you have some other configuration in calendars.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you talking about sharing my google calendar with another google user?

Comment: I guess you have one google id for your work account and one for your private account. So for Google your work email is one user and your private account is another user. You can share colander with yourself.

Comment: My work account isn't a google account.  I don't have the option of sharing my calendar outside the organization.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Microsoft Exchange account for work and I use Outlook on Windows. I have a Android work profile calendar app on my phone. I used the following steps and was able to see my personal calendar events on my work profile calendar app on android phone.

1. On PC, go to Google calendar in browser. Click on Settings for the personal google calendar that you want to add to your work profile app.
2. Under "Integrate Calendar" copy the URL that said "Secret Address in iCal format". You can use public link for public calendars.
3. In Outlook on Windows PC, choose Open Calendar -> From Internet. Paste this URL and click "ok"
4. Sync Android work profile calendar app. It should start showing events from this new calendar added just now.

I cannot yet change the colour of this new calendar in the Android app (setting different colour in Outlook doesn't help). It would be ideal to see them in different colours, but I'll live with this.